# Python override list of object

Tags: python, list, class, overriding, python-3.3

Good morning,

I'd like to create a class who inherited from the list such as I can do :

```
import pickle

object_list = []

object_list.append(an_object)
object_list.append(an_other_object)

object_list.dump('/home/user/my_file')
```

or

```
import pickle

[an_objet, an_other_object].dump('/home/user/my_file')
```

I've just no idea how to create my class,

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
import pickle

class my_list(list):
  def__init___(self, *args)
    list.__init__(self, *args)

  def dumps(self, path):
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
      pick = pickle.Pickler(f)
      pick.dump(self)

  def load(self, path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
      pick = pickle.Unpickler(f)
      for i in pick.load():
        self.append(i)
```